# Auto generate JSON/XML from tabular sql result

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, xml, postgresql

I need to generate JSON/XML from tabular result. In MS SQL Server there is built in function: FOR XML AUTO

For example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Person] P
  LEFT JOIN CAR C ON P.id = C.PersonId
  FOR XML AUTO
```

and as a result I get (out of the box):

```
 <P id="1" Name="jan">
  <C id="1" Name="toyota" Type="osobowyu" PersonId="1" />
  <C id="2" Name="vw" Type="osobowyu" PersonId="1" />
</P>
<P id="2" Name="adam">
  <C id="3" Name="passat" Type="test" PersonId="2" />
</P>
<P id="3" Name="piotr">
  <C id="4" Name="kia" Type="test" PersonId="3" />
</P>
```

Which is very cool. I like that the nested level appears automaticaly for each JOIN. Very cool feature.

Now I wonder if there is something similar for postgres DB?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

No, Postgres has not any similar. There is full ANSI SQL/XML support and partial ANSI SQL/JSON support. When you need ganerate XML document, you can use XML generating functions like:

```
postgres=# select * from person;
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ name  │
╞════╪═══════╡
│  1 │ jan   │
│  2 │ piotr │
└────┴───────┘
(2 rows)

postgres=# select * from car;
┌────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ id │  name  │ personid │
╞════╪════════╪══════════╡
│  1 │ toyota │        1 │
│  2 │ vw     │        1 │
│  3 │ kia    │        2 │
└────┴────────┴──────────┘
(3 rows)
```

```
select xmlelement(name p, xmlattributes(p.id, p.name),
                  xmlagg(xmlelement(name c, xmlattributes(c.id,
                                                          c.name,
                                                          c.personid))))
    from person p join car c on p.id = c.personid
    group by p.id, p.name;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                            xmlelement                                             │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ <p id="1" name="jan"><c id="1" name="toyota" personid="1"/><c id="2" name="vw" personid="1"/></p> │
│ <p id="2" name="piotr"><c id="3" name="kia" personid="2"/></p>                                    │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(2 rows)

Comment: yes thank you, I know this approach. Do you know how it will behave with very large dataset? Let's say that I have on the server 8GB RAM but the result is very large 10 GB XML file.

Comment: @Snorlax - max size of generated XML is 1GB. For longer XML, you have to write client side solution.